# Использование нескольких BackgroundWork

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте!

Хотелось бы узнать, можно ли использовать на одной форме несколько BackgroundWork, например, 10 штук. Не будет ли это влиять на работоспособность и корректность приложения в Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы загружать ими процессор под завязку не будете и разумно отнесётесь к их возможностям, то ничего плохого не будет=)

BackgroundWorker - это, по большей мере, просто отдельный поток приложения. У многих программ их по несколько штук. У того же скайпа штук 30.